# How to get the original HEIC file out of iCloud Photos on the web?

Tags: icloud, photos, heic

I take photos on iPhone with HEIC image support.

How can I get the original HEIC file from iCloud Photos on the web, when browsing on Windows?

I'm using Firefox on Windows 10. When I download a single photo from https://www.icloud.com/#photos
that is (presumably) HEIC because it has HDR and Live photo, I get a ZIP file containing a JPG and a MOV instead.

(Yes, I really want the original HEIC, for testing software)

Comment: Well I worked around it by plugging my phone in and setting the phone settings to keep original, but thats pretty clumsy compared to using icloud

Comment: Specifically on iPhone: Settings > Photos  > "Transfer to Mac or PC" = Keep Originals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I finally found an answer with current iCloud!
Select the photo, then click the ... in a circle button, and then "More Download Options", select "Unmodified Originals", and click Download.

[image: More download options]

[image: Actual download options]